# Can $\Gamma(1/5)$ be written in this form?

Tags: integration, special-functions, gamma-function, elliptic-integrals

## tldr

Feel free to skip to the integrals at the end.

---

I was curious as to whether or not for $n\in\mathbb N$, $\Gamma(1/n)$ satisfies the form

$$\Gamma(1/n)=a\pi^{b/n}\prod_k\operatorname{agm}(1,c_k)^{d_k}$$

Where $a,c_k,d_k$ are algebraic and $b$ is natural and $\operatorname{agm}$ is the arithmetic-geometric mean given by

$$\operatorname{agm}(x,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\\a_0=x,~g_0=y\\a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+g_n}2,\quad g_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_ng_n}$$

The first few values can be derived from [this PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf).

$$\Gamma(1/1)=1$$

$$\Gamma(1/2)=\pi^{1/2}$$

$$\Gamma(1/3)=\frac{\pi^{2/3}2^{2/3}}{3^{1/12}\operatorname{agm}(1,3^{1/4}2^{-1/2})}$$

$$\Gamma(1/4)=\frac{2^{1/2}\pi^{3/4}}{\operatorname{agm}(1,2^{-1/2})}$$

---

However, it does not appear $\Gamma(1/5)$ can be written this way.  The PDF gives

$$\Gamma(1/5)=\pi^{1/5}2^{19/50}5^{1/2}\phi^{1/10}H_1^{2/5}H_2^{1/5}$$

$$\phi=5+\sqrt5\\H_1=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^5}}\\H_2=\int_0^1\frac{x~dx}{\sqrt{1-x^5}}$$

And I'm uncertain about whether or not $H_1$ or $H_2$ can be written in the form of

$$\frac\pi{2\operatorname{agm}(1,\sqrt{1-x})}=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-xt^2)}},~x>0$$

---

> Can $\Gamma(1/5)$ be written in terms of this arithmetic-geometric mean?

Comment: For what its worth, $H_1$ has hypergeometric forms $$H_1=~_2F_1\left(\frac15,\frac12;\frac65;1\right)$$

Comment: $\Gamma(1/5)=\pi^{1/5}2^{19/50}5^{1/2}\phi^{1/10}H_1^{2/5}H_2^{1/5}$ is correct.  But of course that is not the question.

Comment: Lol, thanks for the verification @GEdgar

Comment: $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Beta functions, so can be written in terms of Gamma functions.

Comment: Yes, ofc, but the goal is to get it down to the arithmetic geometric mean, a relatively simple thing to evaluate.  Indeed, using the beta function is how one derives the $\Gamma(1/4)$ formula above.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant lol.  Yes, we have$$H_1=\frac{\Gamma(6/5)}{\Gamma(7/10)}\sqrt\pi$$

Comment: And$$H_2=\frac{\Gamma(7/5)}{\Gamma(9/10)}\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$

Comment: BTW the linked PDF in your question does not give evaluation of $\Gamma (1/3)$ but rather copies the value from mathworld page. Perhaps this evaluation is also desired.

Comment: I think it is also best to mention the original paper (http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0227&DMDID=DMDLOG_0008) of Chowla and Solberg where it is established that if $k$ is a singular elliptic modulus (ie the algebraic number $k$ is given by $$k=\dfrac{\vartheta_{2}^{2}(e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}})}{\vartheta_{3}^{2}(e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}})}$$ for some positive integer $n$) then the integral $$K(k) =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}x}}$$ can be expressed in terms of Gemma values (at rational points) and $\pi$.

Comment: The linked paper in previous comment gives the link between $\Gamma(1/3)$ and elliptic integral $K$ using Kummer's formula for $\Gamma(x) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Interesting, thanks.

Comment: Ramanujan knew the evaluation of $K(k) $ in terms of Gamma values and $\pi$ for some singular moduli $k$. And he mentions the evaluations corresponding to $n=1,2,3$ in his paper *Modular equations and approximations to $\pi$*. This means that the evaluation of the integral $K(k) $ for $k=\sin(\pi/12)$ in terms of $\Gamma (1/3)$ is possible using real analysis methods only.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not an answer.** I still decided to post, because this is too long for a comment. For what it's worth I would bet on a negative answer, i.e. we can't represent $H_1$ and $H_2$ in terms of $\text{agm}$.

I tried to link the integrals from the OP to [Carlson Elliptic Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson_symmetric_form) which are more general than the classic elliptic integrals and have a very nice computation algorithm (which seems to be what the OP wants).

However, the integrals are much more complicated than that.

With simple enough transformations, I was able to express $H_2$ in the following form:

$$H_2=4 \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t+2)(t^4+3t^3+4t^2+2t+1)(t^4+5t^3+10t^2+10t+5)}}$$

$$H_2=4 \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{-1/2}dt}{\sqrt{(t+z_1)(t+z_2)\dots(t+z_9)}}$$

Which translates to the general function $R_{-a}(\mathbf{b},\mathbf{z})$ - see [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.16#ii).

> $$H_2=\frac{2^7}{35} R_{-4} \left(\mathbf{\frac{1}{2}},\mathbf{z} \right) $$

Where $\mathbf{\frac{1}{2}},\mathbf{z}$ are vectors of dimension $9$.

Since the most complicated of Carlson integrals only has $5$ factors under the root, there doesn't seem to be a way to represent $H_2$ in terms of Carlson integrals, or indeed, classic elliptic integrals.

Still, this representation might be useful if one wishes to study the properties of $R_{-a}(\mathbf{b},\mathbf{z})$ in general, which are rather nice.

---

Explicitly $z_k$ can be written the following way:

$$z_1=2$$

Now introducing:

$$a_+=\sqrt{5}+i \sqrt{2(5-\sqrt{5})}$$
$$a_-=\sqrt{5}-i \sqrt{2(5-\sqrt{5})}$$
$$b_+=\sqrt{5}+i \sqrt{2(5+\sqrt{5})}$$
$$b_-=\sqrt{5}-i \sqrt{2(5+\sqrt{5})}$$

We can write the rest as:

$$z_2=\frac{1}{4}(3-a_-)$$
$$z_3=\frac{1}{4}(3-a_+)$$
$$z_4=\frac{1}{4}(3+b_-)$$
$$z_5=\frac{1}{4}(3+b_+)$$
$$ $$
$$z_6=\frac{1}{4}(5+a_-)$$
$$z_7=\frac{1}{4}(5+a_+)$$
$$z_8=\frac{1}{4}(5-b_-)$$
$$z_9=\frac{1}{4}(5-b_+)$$

---

Of course, $H_2$ can also be expressed in a much more simple form as a Hypergeometric function:

$$H_2=\frac{1}{2} {_2F_1} \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{5}; \frac{7}{5};1 \right)$$

---

Meanwhile, $H_1$ can be represented as:

$$H_1=\int_0^\infty \frac{(t+1)dt}{\sqrt{t(t+1)(t^4+5t^3+10t^2+10t+5)}}$$

> $$H_1=\frac{2}{3} R_{-1} \left(\mathbf{\frac{1}{2}},\mathbf{z} \right)+\frac{4}{3} R_{-2} \left(\mathbf{\frac{1}{2}},\mathbf{z} \right) $$

Where $$z_1=1$$

$$z_2=\frac{1}{4}(5+a_-)$$
$$z_3=\frac{1}{4}(5+a_+)$$
$$z_4=\frac{1}{4}(5-b_-)$$
$$z_5=\frac{1}{4}(5-b_+)$$

Even though it's simpler than $H_2$, it still doesn't reduce to Carlson elliptic integrals.

---

We can derive alternative representations for $H_1$ and $H_2$ in terms of $R$ functions, using [the relation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.25#vii):

$${_2F_1}(a,b;c;z)=R_{-a}(b,c-b;1-z,1)$$

However, even these, shorter representations do not reduce to Carlson integrals, but rather to their values in terms of Gamma functions.