# Evaluation of complete elliptic integrals $K(k) $ for $k=\tan(\pi/8),\sin(\pi/12)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

This is inspired from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2387137/72031). I will repeat some information from the linked question for the benefit of readers.

---

Let $k\in(0,1)$ and the elliptic integrals $K, E$ are defined as follows: $$K(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - k^{2}\sin^{2}x}},\,E(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}x}\,dx\tag{1}$$ The number $k$ is called the *modulus* and a complementary modulus $k'$ is defined by $k'=\sqrt{1-k^{2}}$ and if the value of $k$ is available from context then the integrals $K(k), E(k), K(k'), E(k') $ are generally denoted by $K, E, K', E'$.

If $n$ is a positive rational number then it can be proved that there is a unique modulus $k$ such that $K'/K=\sqrt{n} $ and moreover this $k$ is an algebraic number. Such values of $k$ are famous and are called *singular moduli* and one may denote them by $k_{n} $ corresponding to the rational number $n$.

Chowla and Selberg proved in [this paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0227&DMDID=DMDLOG_0008) that

> **Theorem**: Let $k$ be a singular modulus. Then the elliptic integrals $K(k), E(k) $ can be expressed in terms of Gamma values at rational points and $\pi$.

The linked paper of Chowla and Selberg uses theory of quadratic forms and related complex analytic techniques to prove their theorem. On the other hand Ramanujan knew the evaluation of $K$ in terms of Gamma values and $\pi$ for some singular moduli $k$. In his classic paper *Modular Equations and Approximations to $\pi$* he gave the evaluations for $n=1,2,3$ without proof. It is thus reasonable to assume that the evaluations are possible by remaining within the limits of real analysis methods at least for $n=1,2,3$. The case $n=1$ is covered in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793756/72031).

My question  concerns the cases $n=2,3$ for which $k=\tan(\pi/8),\sin(\pi/12)$ respectively:

> Show that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\tan^{2}(\pi/8)\sin^{2}x}}=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} +1} \Gamma (1/8)\Gamma (3/8)}{2^{13/4}\sqrt{\pi}}\tag{2}$$ and $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(\pi/12)\sin^{2}x}}=\frac{3^{1/4}\Gamma ^{3}(1/3)}{2^{7/3}\pi}\tag{3}$$

Evaluation based on real analysis methods is desirable.

---

**Update**: I have managed to prove the above mentioned results using hints given in exercises from Borwein's *Pi and the AGM* (see my answer). But these methods are totally non-obvious and it is desirable to find solutions based on general techniques for evaluation of definite integrals.

Borwein's book was with me for a long time and these exercises lay dormant until I receieved a gentle push via user "Simply Beautiful Art"'s question linked above. Thanks to him for the same.

Comment: From the looks of it, $(2)$ should follow from $B\left(\frac18,\frac38\right)$, seeing that $\sqrt\pi=\Gamma\left(\frac18+\frac38\right)$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : you are right. I will try to start from the beta integral and see if it can be manipulated to get the elliptic integral.

Comment: Note that the form by @SimplyBeautifulArt requires us to have $\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}$ out front still, but we can write $(2)$ more simply as just $2^{-13/4}B\left(\frac18,\frac18\right)$ which looks a little easier to work with

Comment: Interesting fact I found while working on this: $(2)$ can be trivially written as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}}\int _{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{x\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)+\sqrt{2}+3}}dx$$ and naturally one asks if the function inside the integral is symmetric across the y-axis. Graphically, I thought so at first, but it actually has a minimum value at $\approx -0.47$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found a solution for $k = \sin(\pi/12)$. It is taken from an exercise in Borwein's *Pi and the AGM*.

Let's start with the integral $$I(a, b) = \int_{-a}^{a}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a^{2} - x^{2})(b^{2} + x^{2})}}\tag{1}$$ which is equal to $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}}K\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}}\right)\tag{2}$$ Equivalence of $I(a, b)$ with $(2)$ can be seen by writing $K$ as
\begin{align}
K(k) &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - k^{2}\cos^{2}x}}\notag\\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - k^{2} + k^{2}\sin^{2}x}}\notag\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1 - t^{2})(1 - k^{2} + k^{2}t^{2})}}\notag\\
\end{align}
Putting $k = a/\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$ we can see that $$K\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}}\right) = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1 - t^{2})(b^{2} + a^{2}t^{2})}}$$ and using substitution $x = at$ we  get the link between $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Next we use the substitution $x = (1/t) - a$ in $(1)$ to get $$I(a, b) = \int_{1/2a}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(2at - 1)((a^{2} + b^{2})t^{2} - 2at + 1)}}$$ The expression in square root can be expressed as $$2a(a^{2} + b^{2})t^{3} - (5a^{2} + b^{2})t^{2} + 4at - 1$$ and using the substitution $$t = x + \frac{5a^{2} + b^{2}}{6a(a^{2} + b^{2})}$$ the integral is transformed into $$I(a, b) = \int_{e}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4x^{3} - g_{2}x - g_{3}}}\tag{3}$$ where $$g_{2} = \frac{(a^{2} - b^{2})^{2}}{12} - a^{2}b^{2},\, g_{3} = -\frac{(a^{2} - b^{2})\{(a^{2} - b^{2})^{2} + 36a^{2}b^{2}\}}{216}\tag{4}$$ and $e$ is the root of the cubic equation $4x^{3} - g_{2}x - g_{3} = 0$.

Next step is to put $g_{2} = 0$ so that $12a^{2}b^{2} = (a^{2} - b^{2})^{2}$ which gives $$a^{2} - b^{2} = -3(2g_{3})^{1/3}, a^{2} + b^{2} = 2\sqrt{3}(2|g_{3}|)^{1/3}\tag{5}$$ For our case we need to set $g_{3} = 1/2$ so that the root $e = 1/2$ and then we have $$a^{2} + b^{2} = 2\sqrt{3}, a^{2} - b^{2} = -3$$ so that $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}} = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2\sqrt{2}} = \sin(\pi/12)$$ From $(1), (2), (3)$ and above values of $a, b$ it follows that $$K(k) = \frac{3^{1/4}}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{3} - 1}}$$ And putting $x^{3} = 1/t$ we get $$K(k) = \frac{3^{1/4}}{6}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-5/6}(1 - t)^{-1/2}\,dt = \frac{3^{1/4}}{6}\frac{\Gamma(1/6)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(2/3)}$$ This can be expressed in terms of $\Gamma(1/3)$ only (via duplication and reflection formulas) to give the desired form.

---

I must say that the above solution is totally non-obvious and without the hints in the exercise it does not appear possible to arrive at this solution. The value of $K(\sin(\pi/12))$ was first obtained by Legendre using a similar non-obvious approach.

---

Borwein's book provides the evaluation of $K(\tan(\pi/8))$ as an exercise in a later chapter. But this is based on the representation of $2K(k)/\pi$ as the hypergeometric function ${}_{2}F_{1}(1/2,1/2;1;k^{2})$. To simplify typing we will use $F$ instead of ${}_{2}F_{1}$ in what follows.

The following two hypergeometric transformations are needed to create the magic
\begin{align}
&F(a, b; a - b + 1; x)\notag\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,= (1 - x)^{1 - 2b}(1 + x)^{2b - a - 1}F\left(\frac{a - 2b + 1}{2}, \frac{a - 2b + 2}{2}; a - b + 1; \frac{4x}{(1 + x)^{2}}\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
and $$F\left(a, b; a + b + \frac{1}{2}; 4x(1 - x)\right) = F\left(2a, 2b; a + b + \frac{1}{2}; x\right)\tag{7}$$ Equation $(7)$ is by Kummer and [proved here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/10/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-hypergeometric-series-2.html). Equation $(6)$ can be proved in a similar manner but with more difficulty. We start with the equation $$\frac{2K}{\pi} = F\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;k^{2}\right)$$ and put $a=b=1/2, x = k^{2}$ in $(6)$ to get $$\frac{2K}{\pi}=(1 + k^{2})^{-1/2}F\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};1;\frac{4k^{2}}{(1 + k^{2})^{2}}\right)$$ Using $a = 1/8, b = 3/8, x = 4k^{2}/(1 + k^{2})^{2}$ in $(7)$ we get $$\frac{2K}{\pi}=(1 + k^{2})^{-1/2}F\left(\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8};1; X\right)\tag{8}$$ where $$X = 4x(1 - x) = \frac{16k^{2}(1 - k^{2})^{2}}{(1 + k^{2})^{4}} = \left(\frac{4kk'^{2}}{(1 + k^{2})^{2}}\right)^{2}$$ It's time to put $k = \tan(\pi/8) = \sqrt{2} - 1$ to get $X = 1$ (check this!). And thus we finally get $$K(\tan(\pi/8)) = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{4 - 2\sqrt{2}}}F(1/8, 3/8;1;1)$$ And then we use the formula $$F(a,b;c;1) = \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c - a - b)}{\Gamma(c - a)\Gamma(c - b)}\tag{9}$$ to get $$K(\tan(\pi/8)) = \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}\pi}{2^{7/4}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(7/8)\Gamma(5/8)}$$ which simplifies to the given form using the reflection formula and $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$.

---

The transformation $(6)$ is non-obvious and it is used by Borwein brothers to link Ramanujan's alternative theory of theta functions (those dealing with $F(1/4, 3/4;1; x)$) with the standard theory (dealing with $F(1/2, 1/2;1;x)$). This is a key step in Borwein's proof of Ramanujan's famous series for $1/\pi$ and this particular development is well covered in [my blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-3.html).

Comment: ... Wow. No way on earth would I have thought of a solution like that. Nice find!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: I have exactly the same feeling and I have expressed it at the end of my answer. The real miracle is the choice of $a, b$ to get the specific value of the modulus $k = \sin(\pi/12)$.

Comment: After having stared at this a while and letting it sink in, I am beginning to wonder if a similar approach could solve $(2)$...

Comment: $(3)$ has a very nice integral form (up to a scalar), $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}$. Have you found anything akin to this for $(2)$? Best I can get so far for $(2)$ (up to a scalar) is $\int _0^1\frac{1}{(1-t^8)^{7/8}}dt$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Haha, I too have the same feeling. Have recently been trying to work out integrals of the form$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}}$$and I think this is the approach I should take.

Comment: Never thought to use the substitution $x=1/t + a$. I did try $x=1/t$, but yeah... :D +1 @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt substitutions like that are actually quite common when working with quartics and cubics... They are often used to turn a Quartic into a reduced Quartic or a cubic into a reduced cubic for example. Of course, the trick is in knowing what $a$ should be and in when to use such a substitution :)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen :-) I don't actually deal with quartics and cubics very often, and on top of that, I already have my own approaches for factoring/reducing quartics and cubics, though the nice thing here was that the bounds worked out perfectly.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : if $\alpha$ is a root of the quartic $f(x) $ then the substitution $x-\alpha=1/t$ will turn it into cubic. This seems to be a standard procedure in dealing with general elliptic integrals. I got all the information in the hint in Borwein's book which gave reference of Whittaker and Watson's *A Course of Modern Analysis*. Whittaker & Watson (like Hardy) only confirm the saying "old is gold".

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen : the evaluation for $k=\tan(\pi/8)$ was not done by Legendre and is perhaps recent. My guess is that it is based on a different but non-obvious technique.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen : Borwein's book gives another exercise  in a later chapter where the evaluation of $K(\tan(\pi/8))$ is done by using the hypergeometric representation of $2K(k)/\pi $ as ${}_{2}F_{1}(1/2,1/2;1;k^{2})$ and the use of certain transformations of hypergeometric functions. Will update this in the answer after some time. This seems to indicate that perhaps no one has done the evaluation using integration techniques. But I still hope for an integral based answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Interesting! I actually played around with the Hypergeometric form a bit earlier and tried some transformations (unsuccessfully, albeit it briefly), but I decided that it felt like too heavy a tool and I wanted to find something simpler. That being said, I would love to see such a solution!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen : you will have to wait for quite some time as it is a Sunday morning here and there are many chores to be done before I can get onto my laptop. These comments come via smartphone.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  I understand completely :) Take as much time as you need - I'll gladly wait!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: See the updated answer which deals with $K(\tan(\pi/8))$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: See the updated answer which deals with $K(\tan(\pi/8))$.

Comment: Jeez. I was actually attempting the same idea for $\tan(\pi/8)$! Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with the hypergeometric functions' transformations and could not get the last argument down to $1$. Again, nicely done!

Answer (score 5):

I worked out a solution for $k=\tan(\pi/8)$ without using hypergeometric function.

Let $t=\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt2}2}z$, we get
$$
K(\tan(\pi/8))=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-\left(\sqrt2-1\right)^2t^2}}
=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}\frac{\mathrm dz}{\sqrt{z^4-4z^2+2}}
$$
Let $\displaystyle x=\frac{2z}{\sqrt{z^4-4z^2+2}}$, we get
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^4+4x^2+2}}=
\sqrt2\int_0^{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}\frac{\mathrm dz}{\sqrt{z^4-4z^2+2}}
$$
Finally let $\displaystyle x=u-\frac1u$ and we can get a nice integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^4+4x^2+2}}=
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(1+u^2)\,\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1+u^8}}=
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1+u^8}}
$$
Therefore,
$$
K(\tan(\pi/8))=\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt2}2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1+u^8}}=
\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt2+1}\Gamma(\frac18)\Gamma(\frac38)}{2^{13/4}\sqrt\pi}
$$

Comment: Very nice solution. +1

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen +1.

Comment: Could you explain how did you get the substitution because it seems non-trivial to me, perhaps it was inspired by some transformation theory?