# please help me finish the proof of this equation

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

problem: prove that $ 2(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})\sqrt[4]{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})^{2}-x}} dx = \beta (\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3}) $

My attempt:
use the relationship between hypergeometric series and elliptic integral, we have

$F_{1}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,x) = \frac{1}{\beta (\beta,\gamma-\beta)}\int_{0}^{1}t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma -\beta -1}(1-tx)^{-\alpha} dt $
(here $ \beta() $ refers to the Beta function)

then

$ LHS = 2\sqrt[4]{3}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{1}{2}-1}(1-x)^{1-\frac{1}{2}-1}(1-(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})^{-2}x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx $

$ = 2\sqrt[4]{3}\beta (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) F_{1}(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},1,(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})^{-2}) $

$ = \pi \cdot 2\cdot \sqrt[4]{3} \cdot \frac{2}{\pi} \kappa ((\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}) $

$ = 4 \sqrt[4]{3} \kappa ((\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}})$

(here we use $ \kappa (k) = \frac{\pi}{2}F_{1}(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},1, k^{2}$)

Thus, we only need to prove the following equation:

$ \kappa (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}})=\frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{3}}\beta (\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3}) $

I got stuck here, can anyone help me finish this?

note: $ \kappa () $ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac1{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}} = \lambda^*(3),$ where $\lambda^*$ is defined [here.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html)

Now, this seems to imply that
$$K(\frac1{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}}) = \frac{3^{\frac14} \Gamma^3(1/3)}{2^{7/3}\pi},$$ [as per this page.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html)

Comment: thank you very much! this is an inspiring comment and it helped me solve this problem. Yet i don't know how could i calcute K(λ∗(3)) though the answer is shown in the page, could you help me? thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherFu The proof is contained in the 1967 paper of Chowla and Selberg. I fear that the best I can do is to refer you to this paper.I don't have access right now - the result is rather nontrivial, I fear.

Comment: I've got that paper, thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherFu: an elementary proof by Legendre is [available in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2391675/72031).