# Standard values of elliptic functions

Tags: calculus, gamma-function, elliptic-functions

I am wondering about how this value is derived.

The definition of the elliptic integral of first kind $K(k)$ is used from Wolfram Alpha (which wierdly goes against the wikipedia definition. $K(k)$ in Wolfram is equal to $K(k^{2})$ in Wikipedia, I think.)

$\begin{align}
K(\frac{1}{2})&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{2}x}}dx\\
&=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{2\Gamma^2(\frac{3}{4})}\approx1.854
\end{align}$

I have searched the internet and math.se for days and could not find a proof of this value. All answers to similarly related problems just say that $K(\frac{1}{2})$ is a standard value and "easily derived from the definition".

Also, $E(\frac{1}{2})$ can be derived from $K(\frac{1}{2})$ by Legendre's relation, so I only need to know how to prove the special value of $K(\frac{1}{2})$.

Could somebody please give a proof of this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Try the change of variable $y=\sin^2 x$ to make the beta function $B(1/2,1/4)$ appear.

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry... but after that substitution I get $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}y^{-1/2}(1-y)^{-1/2}(1-y/2)^{-1/2}dy$. Could you help? Thanks!

Comment: Note that $m = k^2 = \sin^2\alpha$. Wolfram uses $K(m)$ while others use $K(k)$.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2391229/72031

Answer (score 1):

(Not seen in a dedicated post, but as an intermediate result in many answers, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793756).)$$
\newcommand{\eqsubst}[1]{\underset{#1}{\phantom{\big[}=\phantom{\big]}}}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\frac12\sin^2 x}}\quad\eqsubst{\color{blue}{y=\cos x}}\quad\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+y^2}}\,\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}
\\\eqsubst{t=y^4}\frac1{2\sqrt2}\mathrm{B}\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)\color{gray}{=\frac{\Gamma^2(1/4)}{4\sqrt\pi}=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{2\Gamma^2(3/4)}}
$$
and similarly for *the elliptic $E$*.

Comment: I was going to add a comment (to the question) with a link to my answer but then noticed that you have already linked it in your answer. +1